# How to check the corresponding files from the predict_generator() output in R keras

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras

I have the following code. The data set can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjt5o31oyqj10m8/data.tar.gz?dl=0) or [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data). The data set contains images categorized as `cat` or `dog`.

The task of this code is for training cats and dogs image data.
So that given a picture, it can tell whether it's cat's or dog.
It is motivated by this [page](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/keras-image-classification-on-small-datasets.html). Below is the sucessfully running code:

```
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)


# Organize dataset --------------------------------------------------------
options(warn = -1)

# Ths input
original_dataset_dir <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs/original/"


# Create new organized dataset directory ----------------------------------

base_dir <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs_small/"
dir.create(base_dir)

model_dir <- paste0(base_dir, "model/")
dir.create(model_dir)

train_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "train")
dir.create(train_dir)

validation_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "validation")
dir.create(validation_dir)

test_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "test")
dir.create(test_dir)

train_cats_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "cats")
dir.create(train_cats_dir)

train_dogs_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(train_dogs_dir)

validation_cats_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "cats")
dir.create(validation_cats_dir)

validation_dogs_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(validation_dogs_dir)

test_cats_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "cats")
dir.create(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(test_dogs_dir)

# Copying files from original dataset to newly created directory
fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(train_cats_dir)
)


fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(validation_cats_dir)
)

fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(test_cats_dir)
)

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(train_dogs_dir)
)

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(validation_dogs_dir)
)

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(
  file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
  file.path(test_dogs_dir)
)

options(warn = 0)

# Making model ------------------------------------------------------------


conv_base <- application_vgg16(
  weights = "imagenet",
  include_top = FALSE,
  input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)
)


model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  conv_base() %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

summary(model)

length(model$trainable_weights)
freeze_weights(conv_base)
length(model$trainable_weights)



# Train model -------------------------------------------------------------

train_datagen <- image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1 / 255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)

# Note that the validation data shouldn't be augmented!
test_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1 / 255)

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  train_dir, # Target directory
  train_datagen, # Data generator
  target_size = c(150, 150), # Resizes all images to 150 × 150
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary" # binary_crossentropy loss for binary labels
)

test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  test_dir, # Target directory
  train_datagen, # Data generator
  target_size = c(150, 150), # Resizes all images to 150 × 150
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary" # binary_crossentropy loss for binary labels
)

validation_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  test_datagen,
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary"
)


# Fine tuning -------------------------------------------------------------


unfreeze_weights(conv_base, from = "block3_conv1")

# Compile model -----------------------------------------------------------



model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 2e-5),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)



# Evaluate  by epochs  ---------------------------------------------------------------

#  # This create plots accuracy of various epochs (slow)
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 50, # was 50
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)

# Plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
# plot(history)
```

And the evaluation, with prediction probability code is this

```
# Check classes of data  --------------------------------------------------

train_generator$class_indices


# Evaluate ----------------------------------------------------------------
model %>% evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps = 50)
#$loss
#[1] 0.3161949
#$acc
#[1] 0.932

predict <- model %>%
  predict_generator(test_generator, step = 50, verbose = 1)
```

The output of `predict` is:

```
as.tibble(predict) %>%
  rename(predict_proba = V1) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(predict_proba > 0.5, 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(label = as.integer(label)) %>% 
  mutate(label_name = ifelse(label == 0, "cat", "dog")) %>% 
  head(n=5)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  predict_proba label label_name
#          <dbl> <int>      <chr>
#1  1.000000e+00     1        dog
#2  4.278725e-02     0        cat
#3  4.198529e-15     0        cat
#4  8.683033e-06     0        cat
#5  1.000000e+00     1        dog
```

My question is based on the probability given in `predict` I'd like to know
the corresponding files as stored in `test_dir`?

Basically I want to check by eye if the probability assignment is correct and reasonable.

The structure of my `base_dir` directory is this:

```
.
|-- model
|-- test
|   |-- cats
|   `-- dogs
|-- train
|   |-- cats
|   `-- dogs
`-- validation
    |-- cats
    `-- dogs
```

[image]

**Update**

I tried [sladomic] suggestion. And make the following code:

```
stat_df <- as.tibble(cbind(predict, test_generator$filenames)) %>%
  # assign prediction probability for filenames
  rename(
    predict_proba = V1,
    filename = V2
  ) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label = ifelse(predict_proba > 0.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label = as.integer(predicted_label)) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label_name = ifelse(predicted_label == 0, "cats", "dogs")) %>%
  # image name is the true label name
  separate(filename, into=c("true_label","fname"), sep = "[//]" )

stat_df
```

I get the following data frame:

```
> stat_df
# A tibble: 1,000 x 5
          predict_proba true_label        fname predicted_label predicted_label_name
 *                <chr>      <chr>        <chr>           <int>                <chr>
 1 2.45413622756985e-09       cats cat.1501.jpg               1                 dogs
 2 4.18112916275648e-20       cats cat.1502.jpg               1                 dogs
 3 1.25922511529097e-07       cats cat.1503.jpg               1                 dogs
 4 3.76460201987477e-14       cats cat.1504.jpg               1                 dogs
 5 6.77461059694906e-07       cats cat.1505.jpg               1                 dogs
 6 0.000256105791777372       cats cat.1506.jpg               0                 cats
 7    0.959224164485931       cats cat.1507.jpg               1                 dogs
 8 0.000318235805025324       cats cat.1508.jpg               0                 cats
 9 9.03555774129927e-05       cats cat.1509.jpg               1                 dogs
10 2.40483113884693e-05       cats cat.1510.jpg               1                 dogs
```

I check the from 1000 test images these are the proportion of the predicted labels:

```
> stat_df %>% group_by(predicted_label_name) %>% summarise(n=n())
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  predicted_label_name     n
                 <chr> <int>
1                 cats   191
2                 dogs   809
```

And I check the number of prediction correctly predicted as dog or cat

```
 > stat_df %>% filter(true_label == predicted_label_name & true_label == "dogs")  %>% dim()
[1] 439   5
> stat_df %>% filter(true_label == predicted_label_name & true_label == "cats")  %>% dim()
[1] 130   5
```

Which says that out of 809 prediction only 439 is correctly predicted as dogs (that's around 54% accuracy). Why is that? Did I miss something?

Note that the `evaluate_generator()` gives around 93% accuracy.
What's the correct interpretation?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_generator$filenames` gives you a list of the file names

Comment: I'm so sorry. Problem solved. The bug was mine. I fixed it by adding `mutate(predict_proba = as.double(predict_proba)`.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

Problem solved by adding  `mutate(predict_proba = as.double(predict_proba)`, here:

```
stat_df <- as.tibble(cbind(predict, test_generator$filenames)) %>%
  # assign prediction probability for filenames
  rename(
    predict_proba = V1,
    filename = V2
  ) %>%
  mutate(predict_proba = as.double(predict_proba) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label = ifelse(predict_proba > 0.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label = as.integer(predicted_label)) %>%
  mutate(predicted_label_name = ifelse(predicted_label == 0, "cats", "dogs")) %>%
  # image name is the true label name
  separate(filename, into=c("true_label","fname"), sep = "[//]" )
```